# Wave Analytics - Data Limits

Tags: einstein-analytics

In this link, there is a License data storage limit of 100 million rows for Wave. But also there is a dataset storage limit of 250 million. Ultimately which data limit will apply?
[https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_limits.htm](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?type=5&id=bi_limits.htm)

Also there is a Analytics Cloud - Additional Data Rows  of 100 million in license data storage limit section. Does this mean, the limit is 200 million?

Answer (score 1):

250 million rows per platform applies to licences purchased before October 20 2015.

100 million rows per platform applies to licences purchased after October 20 2015.

My understanding is Analytics Cloud - Additional Data Rows of 100 million is an additional licence that can be purchased to increase data limits.

Comment: Reach out to your local Salesforce AE :) They have a few options available to you.